# How do I convert this SQL command from PHP to golang(gorm)?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, go, go-gorm

I have a SQL command in PHP as follows:

`SELECT A.field1 FROM table AS A, field2 AS B WHERE A.field3=B.field3 AND B.field4 = {$var}";`

I have to rewrite this in golang using gorm package and this what I have come up with.

`rows, _ := db.Table("table").Select("A.field1 AS A, field2 AS B").Where("B.field4 = ?", var).Rows()`

Is this correct? How can I write it properly?

Comment: Possibly unrelated but that MySQL query is about +30 years old and insecure. `join` syntax should be used with an `on` for how the data is related. The `field4` should be the only part of the where and the `$var` should be being bound, not directly in string.

Comment: The translated code has no `A.field3=B.field3` relationship defined and `A` is undefined in the opening select. e.g. `A.field1 AS A` is referencing itself which is not possible.

Comment: That is what I thought but it works in php

Comment: `field2` seems to be a table. That's confusing. If you want migrate code 1:1 use `db.Raw`.